# Measure the max value of all previous values in a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

I am trying to make a function that will determine if value in a column of a data frame is a new high.  So for example if I had the following data:

```
x <- rnorm(10,100,sd=5)
x <- data.frame(x)
```

How can I return, TRUE or FALSE in a new column that only takes into account all the previous values.  The resulting table would look something like:

```
           x   new.max
1  102.42810   NA
2  109.22762   TRUE
3  101.97970   FALSE
4  101.49303   FALSE
5   93.30595   FALSE
6   96.77199   FALSE
7  110.96441   TRUE
8   96.27485   FALSE
9  101.77163   FALSE
10 100.78992   FALSE
```

If I try

```
x$new.max <- ifelse ( x$x == max(x$x) , TRUE, FALSE )
```

The resulting table is below, as it calculates the maximum value of the entire column instead of a subset of all the previous values.

```
           x new.max
1  102.42810   FALSE
2  109.22762   FALSE
3  101.97970   FALSE
4  101.49303   FALSE
5   93.30595   FALSE
6   96.77199   FALSE
7  110.96441   TRUE
8   96.27485   FALSE
9  101.77163   FALSE
10 100.78992   FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in function that computes the running maximum, called `cummax()`.

`diff(cummax(x))` will be non-zero at positions where a new maximum is achieved (there's no entry for the first element of `x`, which is always a new maximum).

Putting the pieces together:

```
new.max <- c(TRUE, diff(cummax(x)) > 0)
```

I've set the first element to `TRUE`, but it could just as well be `NA`.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I love learning about functions in R I never new about.